# Are lambda functions nothrow_move_assignable?

Tags: c++, lambda, type-traits

clang-cl (4.0.0-trunk) seems to think yes while vc2015 (update3) thinks no.

Is this implementation defined or the standard dictates how lambda functions should be implemented in terms or nothrow and move assignable?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void test_nothrow_move_assignable(T&&) {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
    << "\n";
}

int main() {
  test_nothrow_move_assignable([]{});
  return 0;
}

// $ clang-cl.exe scratch.cpp
// $ scratch.exe
// true

// $ cl /nologo /EHsc scratch.cpp
// scratch.cpp
// $ scratch.exe
// false
```

Comment: I didn't think closure types were move assignable at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clang bug. From [expr.prim.lambda]:

> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has no default constructor and a **deleted copy assignment
>   operator**. It has a defaulted copy constructor and a defaulted move constructor (12.8).

So the type shouldn't be move assignable at all, much less nothrow move assignable.

Comment: The funny part is that I started reading the line immediately after your emphasis while looking at the standard on mobile and completely missed the statement about the copy constructor. Good catch. +1